# What regex can I use to match a percentage of a string?

Tags: mysql, regex

For example, let's say I have the strings "STARBUCKS #999", "STARBUCKS NYC", "STAR-BUCKS SEA 109"

I want to use regex to query a MySQL database and match the given strings with the column name eg. "starbucks" (or any other name). The problem is, the strings vary and cannot be predicted so I need to match something like 70% of the word so that I can be reasonably confident that I have a match. Is that something that can be done with simple regex or is it a more complicated problem?

Comment: you can use sql to write something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column LIKE '%starbucks%';`. You'd need to do something to strip out the '-' in 'STAR-BUCKS' so that could be matched, but that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: For your example you could match the regex `\bSTAR\-?BUCKS\b` (possibly with a case-indifferent flag). If that must be at the beginning of the string, replace the first word break (`\b`) with a beginning-of-line anchor (`^`). Beyond that, you would need give us the rules for determining what is a match. We can't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the fulltext search index to achieve your goal.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE input_table (
  input TEXT
) ENGINE=MYISAM; -- InnoDB does not support fulltext search index on temporary tables

ALTER TABLE input_table ADD FULLTEXT SEARCH(input);

INSERT INTO input_table (input)
SELECT ('STARBUCKS NYC')
UNION
SELECT ('STAR-BUCKS SEA 109')
UNION
SELECT ('STARBUCKS #999')
UNION
SELECT ('SOMETHING ELSE');

SELECT input, match(input) against('>starbucks <star <bucks' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as `match` from input_table;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE input_table;
```

More about fulltext search you can check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html).